# How to obtain USB drive capacity on Android?

Tags: java, android

How to obtain the capacity of a USB drive on Android. Some devices mount USB drives to/mnt/media_rw.

Cannot obtain the capacity of the USB drive through StatFs. The files in the USB drive will not be scanned into MediaStore, so they cannot be obtained through MediaStore. My app is not a system application. Is there any way to obtain capacity?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe execute `/system/bin/df`?

Comment: Just curious - what you need that information for?

Comment: What I am doing is a file management app that can transfer files to and from a USB drive. It needs to display the capacity and remaining space of the USB drive

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;

public long getAvailableSpace(){
    long bytes;
    StatFs stateFS = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    bytes = (long)stateFS.getBlockSize() * (long)stateFS.getAvailableBlocks();
    long availableSpace = bytes / (1024 * 1024);
    return availableSpace;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this code is for obtaining the capacity of the phone itself and cannot obtain the capacity of a USB drive

Comment: do you want to get capacity of mounted devices like removable devices(SD Card, USB storage)?
Could you elaborate for your requirement?

Comment: Yes, using StatFs allows you to obtain the capacity of your phone and also the capacity of a USB drive mounted on '/storage/XXXX'. However, some phones cannot obtain capacity through StatFs when mounting a USB drive to '/mnt/media_rw/XXXX'. I am using DocumentFile to operate the USB drive

Comment: Could you share your code block?